# Get string portion enclosed with special characters using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have string with Following format,

Something {{some key}} another {{another value}} another {{Something another value}}.

And I want to select those string which enclosed in special characters.

Here is what exactly regular expression should select.

{{some key}}
{{another value}}
{{Something another value}}

I created one regular expression, But it is selecting all text from first occurrence of special character to last.

[Here](http://www.regexr.com/3bnri) is what I created.

Comment: Try this http://regexr.com/3bns4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\{\{(.*?)\}\}
```

This also works.

Answer (score 3):

This will do your work

`.+`  1 or more times any character(except `\n`).

`+?` minimal match(Non-Greedy).

```
{{(.+?)}}
```

`()` is capturing group. It will capture string enclosed in `{{` and `}}`